# Method call on commandbutton not called when actionfunction is set an a form field

Tags: visualforce, actionfunction

I have a apex:select which calls a actionfunction and rerenders an output panel. In the same form i also have commandbutton which in turn calls another method.

When i have the actionfunction setup the the method on commandbutton doesnt run. If i remove the onchange method on the apex:select the action mothod on the commandbutton runs.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="renderoperator1" action="{!operator1SO}" rerender="operator1Panel,msgs" status="myStatus">
            <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!fieldAssignTo}" value="field1" />
            </apex:actionFunction>
<apex:pageBlock title="Add Members">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Step 1: Specify Filter Criteria for Accounts">
           <apex:outputPanel >
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Field</th>
                    <th>Operator</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>


                        <apex:selectList value="{!Field1}"  size="1" onchange="renderoperator1(this.value);" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accFieldListSO}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>


                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="operator1Panel">
                            <apex:selectList value="{!operator1}"  size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!operators}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:outputpanel>
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!value1}"></apex:inputText></td>
                    <td>AND</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Field2}"  size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accFieldListSO}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputpanel id="operator2Panel">
                            <apex:selectList value="{!operator2}"  size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!operators}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                         </apex:outputpanel>
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!value2}"></apex:inputText></td>
                    <td>AND</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Field3}"  size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accFieldListSO}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <apex:outputpanel id="operator3Panel">
                            <apex:selectList value="{!operator3}"  size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!operators}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!value3}"></apex:inputText></td>
                    <td>AND</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Field4}"  size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accFieldListSO}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="operator4Panel">
                            <apex:selectList value="{!operator4}"  size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!operators}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!value4}"></apex:inputText></td>
                    <td>AND</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Field5}"  size="1">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accFieldListSO}"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </td>  
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="operator5Panel">
                            <apex:selectList value="{!operator5}"  size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!operators}"/>
                            </apex:selectList>
                         </apex:outputPanel>
                    </td>
                    <td><apex:inputText value="{!value5}"></apex:inputText></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:commandButton value="Go" action="{!Go}"  rerender="opAccounts"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Any thoughts as to why this is happening

Comment: Where is the commandbutton?

Comment: yes could you also please post the part with the commandbutton? Do you have any actionregion tags specified?

Comment: @highfive added the commandbutton code. Its just a normal action call.

Comment: @zokito no action:regions in the code

Comment: @Prady try wrapping the selectlist in the actionregion and using the action support in it. It could do the trick. (If you haven't already resolved this)